# Add text label to toolbar - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am having trouble adding text to the toolbar contained within the navigation controller. This is what I am trying to do:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
label.text = "Delete Pins"
label.center = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), y: view.frame.height)
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

let toolbarTitle = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
navigationController?.toolbar.setItems([toolbarTitle], animated: true)
```

I am trying to get it to the text to show up here to let the user know they are in delete mode, any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to activate your toolbar:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

Your customView seems fine. You could also use and flexibleSpace to setup left/right/center:

```
    let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.toolbarItems = [flexible,toolbarTitle]
```

Comment: Thanks! I added another flexible spacer to the right of the label to center it.